TG bot welcome new group members
I'm making a TG bot in Python using the pyTelegramBotAPI library and encountered a small problem.
The thing is that the bot is being created for a channel discussion group and one of its functions is to welcome new members. But it's not quite working
For testing, I created two regular groups (one private and one public), added the bot (it was funny that it greeted itself at that moment), made it an admin, and then I joined the group with my second account, and the bot welcomed me.
But when I created a channel and a discussion group, added the bot (it greeted itself again), made it an admin, and then joined the discussion group with my second account, the bot remained silent.
Code:
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def welcome_new_member(message):
    print(message)
    for new_member in message.new_chat_members:
        welcome_message = f"Привет, {new_member.first_name}! Добро пожаловать в группу!"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, welcome_message)

Who can tell me what the problem is?
